# How can I do to choose an option from a select when I click on a button using React?

Tags: reactjs, select, react-select

I would like to choose the option "Apple" from the select when I click on the "Apple" button using React

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Select from "react-select";
import "react-select/dist/react-select.css";

class ReactSelect extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      itemtitle: "",
      multi: true,
      multiValue: [],
      options: [
        { value: "Color", label: "Yellow" },
        { value: "Fruit", label: "Apple" },
        { value: "Tool", label: "Spanner" }
      ]
    };
  }
  onTitleChange(e, value) {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    this.setState({ multiValue: e.target.value });
  }
  handleOnChange(value) {
    this.setState({ multiValue: value });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Select.Creatable
          multi={this.state.multi}
          options={this.state.options}
          onChange={this.handleOnChange.bind(this)}
          value={this.state.multiValue}
          showNewOptionAtTop={false}
        />
        <button>Apple</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<ReactSelect />, document.body);
```

The full code of my project is there :

[The full code](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-forked-8gjff6?file=/index.js:0-1109)

How can I do that ? Thank you very much !

Comment: Are you saying when you click `<button>Apple</button>`, the `apples` should automatically be selected in the `select` field? Is that correct?

Comment: yes indeed I want that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update the `select` field value when you click the button something like this.

```
handleOnClick = () => {
    this.setState({ multiValue: [{ value: "Fruit", label: "Apple" }] });
};
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Select.Creatable
                multi={this.state.multi}
                options={this.state.options}
                onChange={this.handleOnChange.bind(this)}
                value={this.state.multiValue}
                showNewOptionAtTop={false}
            />
            <button
                onClick={() => {
                this.handleOnClick();
                }}
            >
                Apples
            </button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Attached a sandbox link also.

[image: Edit React-Select (forked)]